# android socket timeout exception while connecting to device

Tags: android, socket-timeout-exception

I am developing android client that will connect to my pc.
While i am testing it on emulator it work fine.
However, while i try it on real device, i am getting socket timeout exception.

Here is the relevant client code

```
public static final String SERVER_IP = "192.168.1.105"; //your computer IP address
public static final int SERVER_PORT = 500;

...

try {
        //here you must put your computer's IP address.
        InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);

        Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Connecting...");

        //create a socket to make the connection with the server
        Socket socket = null;
        try {
            //Here i am geting the exception
            socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVER_PORT); 
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

This is the server code

```
public class FileServer {
public static void main (String [] args ) throws Exception {
    // create socket
    final int SERVER_PORT = 500;

    System.out.println("Open port "+ SERVER_PORT);
    ServerSocket servsock = new ServerSocket(SERVER_PORT);

    final String FILE_NAME ="C:\\myImages\\Movie-Line.CSV"; 
    File myFile = new File (FILE_NAME);
    System.out.println("File to send "+ FILE_NAME);

    while (true) {
        System.out.println("Waiting...");

        Socket sock = servsock.accept();
        System.out.println("Accepted connection : " + sock);
        OutputStream os = sock.getOutputStream();
        new FileServer().send(os,myFile);
        sock.close();
    }
}

public void send(OutputStream os,File myFile) throws Exception{


    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myFile);
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
    int counter;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

    while((counter = bis.read(buffer))!=-1) 
        os.write(buffer,0,counter);

    os.flush();
    bis.close();
```

Here is my log

```
11-23 23:50:20.327: E/TCP Client(3788): C: Connecting...
11-23 23:50:57.061: W/System.err(3788): java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connection timed out
11-23 23:50:57.092: W/System.err(3788):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.connect(Native Method)
11-23 23:50:57.092: W/System.err(3788):     at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedNetworkSystem.connect(BlockGuard.java:357)
11-23 23:50:57.092: W/System.err(3788):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:204)
11-23 23:50:57.100: W/System.err(3788):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:183)
11-23 23:50:57.100: W/System.err(3788):     at java.net.Socket.startupSocket(Socket.java:705)
11-23 23:50:57.108: W/System.err(3788):     at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:263)
11-23 23:50:57.108: W/System.err(3788):     at com.example.atcpclient.TcpClient.run(TcpClient.java:122)
11-23 23:50:57.116: W/System.err(3788):     at com.example.atcpclient.ClientActivity$ConnectTask.doInBackground(ClientActivity.java:167)
11-23 23:50:57.116: W/System.err(3788):     at com.example.atcpclient.ClientActivity$ConnectTask.doInBackground(ClientActivity.java:1)
11-23 23:50:57.124: W/System.err(3788):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
11-23 23:50:57.124: W/System.err(3788):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
11-23 23:50:57.124: W/System.err(3788):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
11-23 23:50:57.132: W/System.err(3788):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
11-23 23:50:57.132: W/System.err(3788):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
11-23 23:50:57.139: W/System.err(3788):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
```

Comment: Are you sure the server is visible to the Android device?  If it is on a private network and the Android is using a mobile network, they probably cannot see each other.  Try putting them both on the same wifi network.

Comment: I am not using wifi for now (although this  is my intention in the end). I just connect my phone through the usb.

Comment: The USB cable would not normally give you a network connection.  It might work as a side effect of enabling tethering, but probably with a different IP address.  Try wifi, it is usually the simplest for testing.